# Creating a dictionary in python from a text file

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got a text file that looks like this:

```
01:Pronoun
02:I
03:We
04:Self
05:You
06:Other
07:Negate
08:Assent
09:Article
10:Preps
11:Number
12:Affect
...
```

Now i want to make a dictionary of this.. A dictionary that looks this way:

```
{'01:': ['pronoun'], '02': ['I'],...}
```

This is the code I've got so far, but it doesn't seem to work like I want...

```
with open ('LIWC_categories.text','rU') as document1:
    categoriesLIWC = {}
    for line in document1:
        line = line.split()
        if not line:
            continue
        categoriesLIWC[line[0]] = line[1:]
```

Comment: do you want the `:` (colon) included in the dict as the key or not?

Comment: your first key is `01:` and second is `02`?

Comment: without the colon.. (sorry for 01: and 02. It should be 01)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want the colon included you can split on the colon to get the key and the value

`key, value = line.split(':')`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a larger problem. What are you trying to do, and why did you choose this approach?

A couple comments:

- A dictionary where the keys are sequential numbers isn't much different from a list. Why not use a list?
- The numbers 01 and 1 are the same number. If your keys are numbers,
  you can't distinguish between those two.
- You can't easily compare a dictionary where the keys are numbers to a
  dictionary where the keys are string representations of numbers.

This will create a dictionary with integers for keys, and strings for values:

```
with open ('LIWC_categories.text','rU') as document1:
    categoriesLIWC = {}
    for line in document1:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        key, value = line.split(':')
        if key.isdigit():
            categoriesLIWC[int(key)] = value
        else:
            categoriesLIWC[key] = value
```

If it's not working, you need to be more specific. What isn't working? What are you expecting, and what are you getting?

Comment: The error is now : TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: I'm expecting to get a dictionary with a number as a key, and a word as a value.. or if it's even possible, the number can be the value and the word the key.. but i don't know if that's even possible... It just need something like this: {'01': ['pronoun'], '02': ['I'],...} or like this {'pronoun': ['01'], 'I': ['02'],...}

Comment: You want the keys to be numbers, or string representations as numbers? I changed my answer to provide numbers themselves as keys.

Comment: Thanks! Now just another question... This code changed my original numbers like 01, 02 into 1 and 2.. And my next task consist of linking two dictionaries (dict 1 = a dictionary where the keys are words and the values are numbers, and dict 2 is this one).. Dict 1 looks like this: {'aaien': ['12, 13, 39'], 'aan': ['10']}, dictionary 2 like this:  {'01': ['pronoun'], '02': ['I'],...} ... But now the numbers in dict 1 and dict 2 aren't entirely the same.. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a separator string to split().  In this case, it would be ":".

string.split() will automatically split on whitespace, but there is no whitespace on your lines.  If you want the : in the key, you can always concatenate it with

```
categoriesLIWC[line[0] + ":"] = line[1]
```

Also

```
line[1:]
```

Should be

```
line[1]
```

Comment: Now it gives me this error : TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: That implies to me that categoriesLIWC is a string, but it looks like it's a dictionary.  Maybe I got my syntax messed up. I haven't really used python in awhile.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [27]: dic={}

In [28]: with open("abc.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():                 #if line is not empty
            k,v=line.split(":")          #split at ":" not at whitespaces
            dic[k]=[v.strip()]           #add to dict
   ....:             

In [29]: dic
Out[29]: 
{'01': ['Pronoun'],
 '02': ['I'],
 '03': ['We'],
 '04': ['Self'],
 '05': ['You'],
 '06': ['Other'],
 '07': ['Negate'],
 '08': ['Assent'],
 '09': ['Article'],
 '10': ['Preps'],
 '11': ['Number'],
 '12': ['Affect']}
```